# SanicException: Blueprint instance named 'core.extentions.exceptions' uses an invalid format

Tags: python, rasa, sanic

I tried to install rasa in an image Docker,the Dockerfile contain:

```
RUN pip3 install rasa==3.1.0  
RUN pip3 install rasa-sdk==3.1.1  
RUN pip3 install sanic  
RUN pip3 install sanic-cors  
RUN pip3 install sanic-validation
```

but when i tried to create the container got the next error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "main.py", line 5, in      from core.extentions.exceptions import blueprint as ext_exceptions   File "/rasa-app/core/extentions/exceptions.py", line 9, in      blueprint = Blueprint('core.extentions.exceptions')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/blueprints.py", line 119, in **init**     super().**init**(name=name)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sanic/base/root.py", line 38, in **init**     f"{class_name} instance named '{name}' uses an invalid " sanic.exceptions.SanicException: Blueprint instance named 'core.extentions.exceptions' uses an invalid format. Names must begin with a character and may only contain alphanumeric characters, _, or -.

Have tried with

```
RUN pip install rasa  
RUN pip install rasa-sdk  
RUN pip install sanic  
RUN pip install sanic-cors  
RUN pip install sanic-validation
```

got the same error

I put diferent versions of rasa but without success